# If $F$ is a $\sigma$ -algebra generated by a countable partition, what is $E(X|F)$ for a random variable $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

> If $F$ is generated by a **countable** partition, what is $E(X|F)$ for
>   a random variable $X$?

so we say that  a $\sigma$-algebra $F$ is said to be generated by a partition if there
  is some partition $\{B_i\}$ of $\Omega$ so that every set $A$ in $F$ is a
  union of some parts in the partition, and every such union is in $F$.

I can't see why the fact that the partition is countable matter when we look at the expectancy.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Note that, in order to be $F$-measurable, a function has to be constant on every member of partition.

Comment: If that is true than that would mean that we're taking an expectancy on a constant $C$ which means $E(X|F)=E(C|F)=E(C)=C$, right?

However, I still don't quite understand why it has to be constant on every member of the partition, can you elaborate?

Comment: Oh, my bad, now I see you were talking about the function $E(X|F)$, however what I still don't see is why it has to be constant on every member of the partition?

Comment: Every member of your $\sigma$-algebra $F$ is countable union of elements from the partition. If function $f$ takes two different values in two different points $a,b$ belonging to the same element $A \in F$, $$f(a)=a', \quad f(b)=b' \neq a'$$ then inverse images $f^{-1}(a')$ and $f^{-1}(b')$ can not belong to $F$ (they would have to contain some elements of $A$ but not the others).

Comment: Of course, above I meant inverse images $f^{-1}(\{a'\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{b'\})$

Comment: I see, and from that we can directly derive that E(X|F)=X or we need to do some more work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every member of your $\sigma$-algebra $F$ is countable union of elements from the partition. If function $f$ takes two different values in two different points $a,b$ belonging to the same element $A$ of the partition,
$$f(a)=a', \quad f(b)=b' \neq a'$$ then inverse images $f^{-1}(\{a'\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{b'\})$ can not belong to $F$ (they would have to contain some elements of $A$ but not the others).

This means that every $F$-measurable function has to be constant on every member of the partition. In particular, conditional expectation can be written as $$E(X \mid F)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i \chi_{A_i}$$ where $\mathcal C = \{A_1,A_2,\ldots\}$ is partition which generated $F$. Since
$$E(E(X \mid F) \chi_{A_i}) = E(X \chi_{A_i}) = c_i P(A_i)$$ we get that 
$c_i = \displaystyle \frac{E(X \chi_{A_i})}{P(A_i)}$.

Comment: "...then inverse images $f^{-1}(\{a'\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{b'\})$ can not belong to $F$ (they would have to contain some elements of $A$ but not the others)."

I understand why if this is true it's a contradiction to the fact that f is F-measurable but I can't really grasp why it's true, can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Points $a$ and $b$ belong to the same element of partition $A$. Inverse image $f^{-1}(\{a'\})$ contains $a$ (since $f(a)=a'$), but does not contain $b$ (since $f(b)=b' \neq a'$). But every member of $F$ is countable union of elements from partition, so it either contains the whole $A$ or does not contain any element from $A$.

Comment: I finally got it, thank you!